# MacTeX 2020: error with report + hyperref + mathbf in chapter

Tags: hyperref, latex-base, bugs

I am getting an error with the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{This raises an error: \(\mathbf{x}=y\)}

test

\chapter{Using this instead works: \({\bf x}=y\)}

test

\end{document}
```

The error:

```
Chapter 1.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\non@alpherr #1->\@latex@error {\string #1
                                          allowed only in math mode}\@ehd 
l.5 ...ter{This raises an error: \(\mathbf{x}=y\)}
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've tried adding `\protect` statements before `\(`, `\)`, and `\mathbf` but with no effect. If I happen to switch the order of the two chapters (so a chapter title uses `\bf` before one uses `\mathbf`), then I don't get an error. I'm completely baffled. The error also goes away if I don't include `hyperref`.

I saw the problem on two different machines running OS X (one Catalina, one Big Sur, both with very recent runs of the "TeX Live Utility" to update packages). On a third I did not see the problem until I upgraded to MacTex 2020 and ran TeX Live Utility. I've tried with an Ubuntu virtual machine and I don't see the problem there. As I said, I'm baffled. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/501

Comment: This is fixed in the development sources https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/503

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One step forward two steps back...

ltfssdcl.dtx in the format  has:

```
% \changes{v3.0u}{2020/03/19}{fix for (gnats/3357)}
%    \begin{macrocode}
 \expandafter#1\ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup{#4}\else#4\fi
```

latex/3357 has an interesting discusssion showing this is a tricky area....

https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=anything&keyword=&pr=latex%2F3357&search=

However I think adding two more `\expandafter` is the correct fix here

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\document@select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
   \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\e@mathgroup@top
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\extract@alph@from@version
         \csname mv@\math@version\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\number\csname
                       c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}%
          #1%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used
                   in version \math@version}%
        \@eha
  \fi
 \else \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
%    \end{macrocode}
%    If the legacy interface is used, e.g., \verb=$\sf -1$= the math
%    alphabet \verb=#1= does not take an argument so we better do not
%    surround \verb=#4= with braces, because then we get
%    \verb={\relax}= into the formula and introduce an extra Ord
%    atom. The two different cases can be distinguished by looking at
%    the current value of \cs{math@bgroup}.
% \changes{v3.0u}{2020/03/19}{fix for (gnats/3357)}
%    \begin{macrocode}
 \expandafter#1\ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup{#4}\else#4\fi
 }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\chapter{This raises an error: \(\mathbf{x}=y\)}

test

\chapter{Using this instead works: \({\bf x}=y\)}

test

\end{document}
```

I will raise an issue at the  latex github

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get away with the error by providing a substitution for `\mathbf`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\mathbf\@firstofone
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This works \(\mathbf{x}=y\)}

test

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, using math in bookmarks won't work anyhow, so maybe it's preferable to use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This works better \texorpdfstring{\(\mathbf{x}=y\)}{x=y}}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: this used to work in tl2019 so I suspect we should take this as a bug

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Possibly. Actually it “sort of worked”.

Comment: sure but infinite loop isn't a kind error:-) see my answer I just posted.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as a workaround.